# Метки на фото, сделанные со смартфона

Tags: android, apple

Есть ли технологии, которые позволяют оставлять на фото, сделанных со смартфона, метки частей света. Например, фотографирую и на фото остается метка "Север там".

Практическая реализация не интересует, с этим сам разбрерусь. А вот существует ли такая возможность и написанные библиотеки, вот в чем вопрос. Ищу данное решение, как для андроид, так и для IoS

Comment: Данные с датчика магнитных полей используйте

Comment: Ну поскольку программы типа "Компас" существуют, то, видимо, смартфон может ориентироваться по сторонам света... правда, по моему личному опыту - плюс минус весьма растоптанный лапоть. *Например, фотографирую и на фото остается метка "Север там".* На 2D это бессмысленно. А вот направление камеры при съёмке (типа "камера направлена по азимуту 123 градуса") - имеет смысл. Но я о готовых решениях, которые не то что на фото, а просто выдавали бы подобную информацию, как-то не слышал...

Comment: какого вида метка - слова на изображении? А так-то давно уже есть приложения, которые в exif фиксируют куда направлена камера. Вот вам и метка.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, слова или стрелка, какого вида метка еще не определено. Я в своей голове собираю это как, при запуске приложения (камеры) отображать в реальном времени либо стороны света, либо направление по азимуту, как предложно выше. После того как фото готово, оставлять это значение на самом фото

Comment: ну тогда надо при создании фото считывать с gps направление по сторонам света и рисовать стрелочку. Поищите в маркете всякие gps camera, может, удастся подглядеть что-нибудь стоящее

Comment: @Эникейщик Направление по gps разве не направление движения?).ну т.е. там данные не о том как повернут телефон а куда он двигается....

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков начал углубляться и нашел не только датчик магнитного поля, но и  [геомагнитный датчик](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position). Он вроде как более адаптирован под эту задачу. Остается найти статистику по наличию в устройствах как железки и можно пробовать реализовывать)

Comment: Геомагнитный датчик - по сути просто другое представление данных магнитного датчика :) по крайней мере на моем телефоне это один физический датчик, но разные програмные апи к нему

Comment: В данных GPS есть направление азимута